# Algorithm for returning similar documents represented in Vector space model

Tags: cluster-analysis, document, k-means, tf-idf

I have a DB containing tf-idf vectors of about 30,000 documents.

I would like to return for a given document a set of similar documents - about 4 or so.

I thought about implementing a K-Means (clustering algorithm) on the data (with cosine similarity), but I don't know whether it's the best choice because of many uncertainties: I'm not sure what to put in my initial clusters, I don't know how many clusters to create, I fear the clusters will be too unbalanced, I'm not sure the results quality will be good, etc.

Any advice and help from experienced users will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Katie

Comment: How sparse are your vectors. i.e. average number of terms per doc / per query ?

Comment: Very sparse. There are around 30,000 different 2-4 pages documents.

Comment: How sparse are the queries ? E.g. 5 terms => 30k cos distnces take time ~ 5 * 30k, fast enough ?

Comment: The time also consists retrieving the 30k document vectors from the DB and then calculating the cos distance between the given document and all the other 30k documents. The average number of terms in a vector is 10.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to return for a given document a set of similar documents - about 4 or so.

Then don't do k-means. Just return the four closest documents by tf-idf similarity, as any search engine would do. You can implement this as a k-nearest neighbor search, or more easily by installing a search engine library and using the initial document as a query. [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) comes to mind.

Comment: I fear that calculating the closest documents from a corpus of 30,000 in real time would be inefficient, and on the other hand holding all the similarity results between all document will take too much space.

Comment: @Katie D: you fear, but have you tried it out? 30.000 documents isn't a lot at all, even if they're book-sized. Only k-means might be slow on such a set due to its iterative nature.

Comment: But I'm not sure how it will not be inefficient. If I fetch all the document vectors (one time in and store it in a cache, or every time I want to find a similar document) I will need to query the DB for  30,000 vectors and then store them in-memory so I could iterate on them. Is that what you meant I should do?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you

1. read 30k records from a bigger db to a cache file / to memory
2. cosine similarity, 10 terms * 30k records -> best 4.

Can you estimate the runtimes of these phases separately ?

1. read or cache: how often will this be done,
   how big are the 30k vectors all together ?
2. 10 * 30k multiply-adds: in your c / java / ... or in some opaque db ?
   In c or java, that should take < 1 second.

In general, make some back-of-the-envelope estimates
*before* getting fancy.

(By the way,
I find best-4 faster and simpler in straight-up c than std::partial_sort; ymmv.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll be testing how much space it will take holding all the vectors in-memory, and how fast the calculations are. If there results will be interesting I'll post them back to you.

Comment: Please do -- most people here are interested in real results.